# Animation about three kids who turn into monsters and fight a giant bird at the end

Tags: story-identification, animation

It is the generic trio (the protagonist, the other boy and the girl). They meet little creatures who can merge with them, turning them into monsters (the protagonist is an insect, the other one is a chameleon, and the girl was a fairy, I think). Then they go to other dimensions, and in the end they fight a big black bird. That's all I remember.

Comment: In which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also what was the animation style? Anime? Western?

Comment: It was definitely western, I've watched it in somewhere between 2013-2015, it was in the movie program of cartoon network, that's all i remember